# Statistical Implications of Beta(0,0) in Power Analysis

Tags: r, statistical-power, beta-distribution

My team uses the code below to determine whether certain test rates of components will allow us to detect any significant degradation in component reliability. It compares the beta distribution for a null and alternate distribution and computes relevant alpha and beta/power values.

```
beta.pwr <- function(m, r, n = 100, degrade, alpha){
  # m = test rate  0 < m <= 20
  # r = demonstrated component reliability  0 < r < 1
  # n = Number of previous tests for the component
  # degrade = Minimum Detectable Degrade in component reliability  0 < degrade < r
  # alpha = Max Type I error allowed  0 < alpha < .5

  a1 = (n-1) * r              # Null alpha for beta distribution
  b1 = (n-1)*(1-r)            # Null beta for beta distribution
  a2 = (m-1)*(r-degrade)      # Alt alpha for beta distribution
  b2 = (m-1)*(1-(r-degrade))  # Alt beta for beta distribution
  crit = qbeta(alpha, a1, b1) # Critical value within the null distribution
  pwr = pbeta(crit, a2, b2)   # Power in alt distribution calculated from crit value of null
  pwr
}
```

As a general rule of thumb, higher `m` results in a higher power.  Questions have arisen recently regarding reduced test rates, even perhaps cancelling testing altogether. Calculations were made with drastically reduced test rates. `m = 1:10`. But something curious occurs in the code when `m=1`. Regardless of the given `alpha, degrade` values, `a2 = b2 = 0`, meaning the power `pbeta(crit, 0, 0) = 0.50` for all `0 < crit < 1`. **Why is this? Does this mean that `m=1` is literally a coin flip in correctly accepting the alternative, independent of current reliability `r`?**

The help file for `pbeta` says

> The mean is a/(a+b) and the variance is ab/((a+b)^2 (a+b+1)). These moments and all distributional properties can be defined as limits (leading to point masses at 0, 1/2, or 1) when a or b are zero or infinite, and the corresponding [dpqr]beta() functions are defined correspondingly.

I understand what it's saying, somewhat, but have a hard time grasping the practical application of it should it exist, particularly in relation to my current example. **What is a point mass in practice and how does it apply to my code and situation? Is there some underlying statistical theory I don't quite grasp yet?**

In addition, I've checked myself using the Beta function, it's relation to the Gamma Function, and the Gamma Function's relation to the Factorial. Functionally, `Beta(0,0) = Gamma(0)Gamma(0)/Gamma(0+0) = (-1)!(-1)!/(-1)! = (-1)!` which doesn't exist. Am I jumping to conclusions here?

I don't know if this needs to be said, but it's believed that the purpose of doing `(m-1)` in the code is because of rules regarding degrees of freedom, but this is unverified. It's also believed that `m=0` implies `power = 0`.

Comment: How do you use this calculation?  What do you measure and how do you decide about degradation?

Comment: @abstrusiosity A table of calculated power values is generated with Reliability Values versus Test Rates. This is discussed in great detail to determine the best test rates given the current reliability. There are power, alpha, and degradation specs that have to be reached, so reducing testing rates has its limitations. My question is mostly pertaining to the statistical theory of Beta(0,0)

Comment: I ask because I'm not sure a discussion of Beta(0,0) will really help you.  The setup of the problems sounds Bayesian but then you talk about Frequentist hypothesis testing.  What test statistic do you compute that has a Beta distribution?  As for the Beta(0,0), that is treated as the limit of the Beta distribution as the two parameters both go to zero.  That limit results in a distribution that is either 0 or 1, with probability depending on the ratio (I think) of a and b.  If a and b are equal, then the limiting distribution has equal probability at 0 and 1.

Comment: The test statistic we compute is the Reliability of the components that we test. This comes from the product of subcomponents individual reliabilities. And it is a Frequentist approach., but there are talks of changing to a Bayesian approach. I'm generally not looking at a or b at 0 and 1 because I'm looking at using the current reliability, which is between 0 and 1, as an input.